# Can a many to one relationship be represented in a logical ER diagram?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship, erd

I have a particular problem from my assignment which goes like this :

"Each product making up a set is supplied by a single supplier and is given a unique ID,. Products are always sold as part of a set, never on their own."

So based on this is assumed Many Products creates One Package(aka set), but i don't know if i'm right, if so how can I visually show a Many to One relationship as an ER diagram.

I have constructed my own Conceptual and Logical ER diagram, I just need to know if i'm right or wrong so that i can continue with the rest.

[image]

Comment: it doesn't say that it is always the same package, so one product could be in many packages.

Comment: Could it also be Many to Many ?

Comment: yes, i think so.

Comment: oh thank you so much, i think i would switch to, One to Many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's a breakdown of the assignment and what I get from it:**

> Each product making up a set is supplied by a single supplier and is given a unique ID,. Products are always sold as part of a set, never on their own.

From this I get that we have these entities:

1. Product
2. Supplier
3. Package (Set)

You should know that each Entity needs its own primary key.  Pros will either call this id, or product_id.  There are ORM's that tend to work best out of the box, if you name the pk for each table 'id', especially when it is a simple sequence number.

It's also better not to do what you are doing with attribute names.  In sql people stick with either all uppercase or all lowercase naming rather than camelcase.  Also I'd suggest that you don't name the price attribute pPrice just because it's in the Package table.  Just name it price, because it can be referred to as Package.price if you need to tell it apart from some other table that also contains a price column.

The important thing to understand is that the relationship between Package and Product is *Many to Many*

1. One Product can be part of Many Packages.
2. One Package can contain Many Products

In order to create entities for a Many to Many relationship, you need a table that sits between the 2 tables and will have foreign keys to both tables in it.  Typically people will pick whatever they consider the dominant side -- I would probably use Package, and name the table "PackageProduct" to reinforce the idea that this table lets me package products together and sell or distribute them.

```
PackageProduct
--------------
id (pk)
package_id (foreign key to Package table)
product_id (foreign key to Product table)
```

You also need a supplier table, but you were informed that the relationship between Package and supplier is that a Package can have one and only one Supplier.

This is code for: create a one to many relationship between Supplier and Package.  In doing this, Package will have a foreign key in it that stores the Supplier.id (or supplier_id)

So to conclude you should have these entities (tables):

1. Package
2. Product
3. Supplier
4. PackageProduct

**ERD**

Here's an ERD rendered with "Relational" format which I find a bit more descriptive, as the many sides of the connections use the crowsfoot, so it's very obvious.

[image: ERD]

Comment: It seems you know that a logical relationship is different than a physical model.  In a logical model you can have a many to many relationship between 2 entities.  With a physical relationship, you need the entity/table to physically manifest the logical many to many.

Comment: Also strictly speaking you could have a compound primary key in PackageProduct using package_id, product_id, but in practice it's often better to let the entity have its own unique key.  If you didn't want that for whatever reason, you'd remove the id from PackageProduct, and change the relationships between product and package to packageproduct to be defining.  For an ERD a "defining" relationship causes the foreign key to become all or part of the primary key of the table connected to the many side of the relationship

Answer (score 1):

According to your description your schema will have one to many relation i.e your single package comprises many products.

You can also find out your ERD diagram [image]

Comment: This model enforces that a Product can be a part of one and only one Package.  That would be highly unusual, and unless this was a business rule described as a requirement, I don't think this would be a correct interpretation of the requirement.